# Can someone who has only SP execution rights on an Azure SQL server DB cause any damage to the data or the DB itself

Tags: sql-server, azure, permissions, authorization, azure-sql-database

I would like to grant a user access to a DB to execute an SP (maybe more than one) but I am a concerned that they might still be able to get some data that can be used in a harmful way or cause damage to the service somehow and that I am missing some loophole in the azure security settings.

If I were to grant a user access to an Azure SQL server DB (not master just the DB itself):

```
CREATE USER sp_only_user WITH PASSWORD = 'blabla12345!@#$'
```

and only grant them permission to execute one or more specific stored procedure(s):

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::sp_Get_Clients to sp_only_user
```

Could they change something in the Azure SQL server configuration or database using any SP or function or some other functionality that is publicly available once access is granted?

Thank you

Comment: A `USER` can only perform what they are explicitly `GRANT`ed, or who permissions they inherit from a `ROLE` they are a member of (or AD Group). If the `USER` doesn't have any `ROLE`s (excluding `public`), then they can only do what you explicitly `GRANT` them and what the `public` role can do. Is there something you are specifically concerned they can do? Most Security loopholes aren't going to be documented (Cross Database Ownership Chaining has documented considerations as an example though), and fixes would be worked on and deployed upon discovery or being reported to Microsoft.

Comment: Hi @Larnu  I am aware that users are supposed to be able to do only what they were granted permission to do, however when I created a user as specified in the question I saw that they could still see and even execute various system SP and Functions (e.g. create and delete diagram). This concerns me as there could potentially be other operations they can perform which can cause problems. Not only data theft but also just maybe causing the Db to crash. I dont know what I dont know and hence the question. Thank you.

Comment: Because a member of the `public` role can do all that too; hence why I explicitly mentioned the role.

Comment: @Larnu thanks for the clarification. So that leaves that question as to whether someone with public role access can cause any interruption of service or any other problems

Comment: Like *what*? Again, what specifically are you expecting them to be able to do here you think is a concern? The fact that they can connect could mean that could attempt to run 100,000's of queries at the same time, but that's no different to doing a DDOS attack on a website; all you need is connectivity. It feels like you're looking for something for the sake of looking for something, but don't know what that something is.

Comment: @Larnu that pretty much nails it. I am trying to find out if there is any vulnerability anyone knows about which I am not aware of in providing such access, so that I can evaluate whether to give such access. For the SP that I grant access to I can limit the number of executions. but I suppose they can execute those other SP and functions as much as they want as I cannot change those. Is there anything else you or anyone is aware of. If so it would be good to know.

Comment: I covered this earlier *"Most Security loopholes aren't going to be documented (Cross Database Ownership Chaining has documented considerations as an example though), and fixes would be worked on and deployed upon discovery or being reported to Microsoft."*

Comment: Resource Governor would help to prevent DDOS attacks, although it's not perfect

Comment: @Larnu hi again, is it possible to revoke the public role so that the user, which should only be able to log into the DB and execute 4 SP will not be able to run in system SP, functions, or views? Will the user still be able to log in and execute the 4 SP I want them to be able to?

Comment: You cannot remove someone from the `public` role; if someone is inheriting permissions from the `public` role you don't want them to have, then `DENY` them that permission, or `REVOKE` that permission from the `public` `ROLE` and give other users the permission a different way (such as with a different `ROLE`). Giving permission to the `public` role means you are saying that *any* `USER`s on the database should have that permission.

Comment: @Larnu there are a a couple of thousand system SP, views and functions and access to these are inherited from the public role. Is there a way to deny them all at once, some have to be denied from master, some have to be denied from the DB. I cant execute that many deny statements. It will take me too long. Is there a short cut please?

Comment: You could use the `sys` objects to build the statements. But there is no magic "SQL Server, read my mind to `DENY` this `USER` access to these objects" feature; you need to explicitly tell it.

Comment: @Larnu I tried on one view first. I executed: 
REVOKE SELECT ON sys.all_objects from SP_Only_User ;
(or REVOKE SELECT ON  OBJECT::sys.all_objects from SP_Only_User ;)
Logged in as SP_only_user and can still execute the view. Am I doing something wrong, or is it just not possible to revoke access to system objects?

Comment: *Why* are you trying to `DENY` someone access to `sys.all_objects`..? This feels like it's turning into an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info). Though we way off what the question asked is now; if you have a new question, I suggest posting a new question.

Comment: @larnu its was just an example. Since no one can guaranty me that a system SP cannot be used to cause problems, I want to revoke the users rights to execute any system SP or view or function and restrict them to only execute the 4 SP I prepared for them.

Comment: Definitely an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @Larnu its only become an XY problem since no one can answer whether exec rights on  system SP, functions and views can be used to cause problems and if so how to prevent such exploitation. The answer was to revoke every object separately since public users can access system objects and everyone who can login is a public user. I tried and revoking each doesnt work. So I am still with the same problem: How to guaranty that the system objects are not exploited, which is not an XY problem.

Comment: So I go back to my original question: *"Is there something you are specifically concerned they can do?"* We can't answer your question, because it's effectively "What vulnerabilities are there in SQL Server?" right now; if you want to find out about that then maybe start [here](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-26/product_id-251/Microsoft-Sql-Server.html)

Comment: Unfortunately same answer. Since I do not know the capabilities of the 1000-2000 SP/functions/views, I cannot answer specifically of a capability I am worried about. I am worried about what I do not know. Since its not likely anyone knows except for maybe a security expert or a hacker that exploits oversights, the solution suggested was to revoke all permissions, one by one. When I tried I found this doesnt work always either.

Answer (score 0):

If the Stored procedure has `DELETE`, `UPDATE`, `INSERT` statements then definitely user can make any changes in the table. In other words, if the user doesn't have `INSERT` permission, but they could execute the stored procedure that performs the same `INSERT`.

You can go through [this Microsoft Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/299fcf86-954a-43ba-a9e1-0c08c4596cbb/should-a-call-to-a-sproc-that-inserts-rows-fail-if-user-has-readonly-permissions-to-data?forum=sqlsecurity) discussion which might help you to manage your permissions so that you user can execute only allowed procedures.

Comment: thanks. Though not exactly the answer to my question. If I grant access as per the description in the post, the user gets access to all system object (about 2000). I dont want the user to have access to sys.  objects. How do I create a user that doesnt.